# Using URL parameter in Java Class

Tags: java, servlets, token

I want to make a basic "forgot password" system and I gave a random generated token for each user and stored it in database. The user has to enter his email on a form to request a link for the password reset. Then, he receives an email with a specific link like: http://localhost:8080/login/reset-password.jsp?token=fd6256666910438486e76760952ea71d where the parameter "token" retrieves the token value that is associated with his email in database.

Now, my question is, **how can I get the password updated while getting the token value in URL?**

I have tried to request the parameter from URL but I don't know what I'm missing here because when I'm debugging **it shows me that reset_token is NULL** and because of that, **nothing is updated**. Please help.

Here's my table:

```
CREATE TABLE user (
id bigint identity NOT NULL,
username varchar(50) NOT NULL,
email varchar(50) NOT NULL,
password varchar(50) NOT NULL,
attempts int DEFAULT 3,
state varchar(50) DEFAULT 'Active’,
reset_token varchar(50),
time_token TIMESTAMP,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Here's my servlet:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        String password = request.getParameter("password");
        String token = request.getParameter("token");



                ForgotPasswordHandler.UpdatePassword(password, token);

                String message = "Password changed!";
                request.setAttribute("message", message);
                request.getRequestDispatcher("reset-password.jsp?token=" + token).forward(request, response);   



    }
```

And this is the method from ForgotPasswordHandler.java:

```
public static void UpdatePassword(String password, String token) throws SQLException {

            PreparedStatement ps = null;
            try
            {
                if (con == null){
                    System.out.println("Failed connection");
                } else {
                    ps = con.prepareStatement(
                        "UPDATE user SET password = ? WHERE reset_token = ?");

                    ps.setString(1,password);
                    ps.setString(2,token);

                    ps.executeUpdate();   

                   if (!con.getAutoCommit()) {
                      con.commit();
                   }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace(System.out);    
            } 
            finally {
                if (ps != null) {
                    ps.close();
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

So, after long hours searching, I figured out that the token parameter isn't retrieving anything because in a post request it gets values from the body and not from URL, so I simply added an hidden input inside the form like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="token" value="<%= request.getParameter("token")%>">
```

And it worked perfectly. Hope this helps someone in the future.